# Extracting the return value in Squeak (Smalltalk)

Tags: regex, smalltalk, squeak

I want to extract the return value from a given text that represents a method.

for example:

```
g: x and: y
Transcript show: x; show: y.
^x+y.
```

so to solve I used the regular expression:

```
\^\s*(\w+.*).
```

when I run this on some regex websites it seems to work and do what I want, for example : https://regex101.com/

but when I run the following program it seems that squeak returns `nil` to it (can't find a match). I suspect that is because I am using the character `^`.

but I escaped that character so I have no idea why that is failing to work.

the code I used to test it:

```
|aString regexObj |
aString := 'g: x and: y
Transcript show: x; show: y.
^x+y.'.

regexObj := '\^\s*(\w+.*).' asRegex.
regexObj matches: aString.
returnedType:= (regexObj  subexpression:2). 
Transcript show: returnedType.
```

anyone knows why, and how to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Aviad, why did you try to acces subexpression *2*? There is only one capturing group, so it should be `(regexObj  subexpression:1)`

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, it may be simpler to generate the AST and access the return node. E.g. `(MyClass>>#myMethod) parseTree nodesDo:[ :node | ... ]` (untested).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew from some side testing and by reading the documentation you will see that subexpression 1 will give you the entire match while subexpression 2 will give you the group in the parentheses.
the documentation: [link] (https://ci.inria.fr/pharo-contribution/job/UpdatedPharoByExample/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/book-result/Regex/Regex.html)

Comment: @MaxLeske can you please explain in more details, and give maybe a reference to how to do it? thanks!

Comment: @AviadShiber: Good link, it is clearer now. But still, look at your code and examples in the docs. Yours should look like `regexObj := '\^\s*(\w.*)\.' asRegex.` => `regexObj search: aString` => `regexObj subexpression: 2` - NOTE: `search` is used to look for partial matches, while `matches` needs a whole string match. At least try replacing `matches:` with `search:` in your code.

Comment: It would also help if you could clear out the actual requirements: do you only need to extract a part of the line that starts with `^`, then has 0+ whitespaces and then your required value starts with a word char after which you grab the rest of the line? Or do you need to parse arithmetic expressions (then, AST is the way to go)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew replacing matches with search  fixed it! thanks!! :).
</br>

basically my task is to check types in runtime with some given types that I already extracted based on comments in the code. 
so after extraction I need to inject the code to the compile method in Behaviour class.

Comment: Ok, I will post the answer to explain the difference between `matches` and `search`, but if you have a problem with the regex, let know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace the method from `matches` to `search`. See [139.6. Matching](https://ci.inria.fr/pharo-contribution/job/UpdatedPharoByExample/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/book-result/Regex/Regex.html):

> `matches: aString` — true if the whole argument string (`aString`) matches.

and

> `search: aString` — Search the string for the first occurrence of a matching substring. Note that the first two methods only try matching from the very beginning of the string. Using the above example with a matcher for `a+`, this 
>   method would answer success given a string `'baaa'`, while the previous two would fail.

*The first two methods* refers to `matches` (requiring a full string match) and `matchesPrefix` (that anchors the match at the start of the input string). The `search` allows matching the pattern *anywhere* inside the string.

A note on your regex: the final `.` is not escaped and matches any non-line break char. You should escape it to match a literal dot:

```
'\^\s*(\w.*)\.'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GI4gIi/1).

Also, `\s` match match across lines. If you do not want it, replace `\s` with `\h` (a PCRE pattern that matches only horizontal whitespaces). Watch out for the `.*` pattern: it will match any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as *many* as possible, so, it will match up to the last `.` on a matching line.

Comment: thanks!
I really missed it and now it is much more clear to me :)

Comment: I dont know why but with search in catch more info than needed, for example:
{code}
|aString regexObj  returnedType |
aString:='g: x and: y
"@Private" Transcript show: x; show: y.
^ x+y .
"@ArgsTypes: SmallInteger,
SmallInteger.
"@RetType: Boolean"'.


regexObj := '\^\s*(.+)\.' asRegex.
regexObj search: aString.
returnedType:= (regexObj  subexpression:2). 
Transcript show: returnedType.
{code}

and \h does not work in squeak.

Comment: It is written it uses PCRE regex flavor. It is not right then, if `\h` is not supported. As I noted, `.*` matches as many chars as possible. Maybe you need `.*?`? Could you please share a http://regex101.com fiddle showcasing the issue?

Comment: fixed it by using the follow regex: \^([^.]*)\.

in regex101 the problem was now shown, only in smalltalk.

Comment: Yes, just make it non-greedy. The `[^.]*` matches 0+ chars other than a dot, so it will make it up to the *first* dot.

Comment: Just from interest: doesn't `.*?` work? Are lazy quantifiers supported?

Comment: no they are no supported, I get the "invliad lookaround expression" error.

Comment: Ok, I found that [*"the matcher passes H. Spencer's test suite"*](http://live.exept.de/doc/online/english/programming/goody_regex.html#IMPLEMENTATION). No lazy quantifier support mentioned.

Comment: Hi again Wiktor,
when I use the following regex: https://regex101.com/r/oY82RO/2
I also get a match with the following line of ArgTypes.. I want to have a match with only between "@RetTypes:(...)."
do you have any idea what can I do?

thanks.

Comment: Sorry, regex101 does not work on a mobile. If you need to extract part of text between `@RetTypes(` and `)`, use `@RetTypes\(([^)]+)\)`.